# Get data from Meteor Collection for CountdownTimer

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I want to set a CountdownTimer to a specific date what the user has picked. I saved the date in a Meteor Collection

```
Template.addDate.events({
    'submit form':function(event){
         var closeDate = $('[name="date"]').val();
     Date.insert({
    closeDateDB: closeDate,
         )};
    }
});
```

Now i want to get this Data from the Collection and set my new endtime in my Timer to this picked Date.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    var endtime = Data.findOne(???);
    timeinterval = setInterval(function () {
      Meteor.call("getCurrentTime", function (error, result) {
        Session.set("time", result);
        var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);
        Session.set("t", t);
      });
    }, 1000);
  });
```

How can i get the inserted date in my Database and use it for my Timer? How to fill the "???" in

```
Data.findOne(???);
```

EDIT___

I try to define better what i want to achieve. 
If the user enters the site he shoud fill out a form. Something like this:

```
Template.addQuestions.events({
    'submit form':function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var questionText = $('[name="questionName"]').val();
      var categoryText = $('[name="categoryName"]').val();
      var closeDate = $('[name="date"]').val();
      Questions.insert({
        closeDateDB: closeDate,
        categoryDB1: categoryText,
        questionDB: questionText,
        createdAt: new Date(),
      }, function (error,results){
      Router.go('decision', {_id:results});
      }
```

As you can see i got the closeDateDB where the user is able to pick a date by a datepicker. I used `tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker`. After this the user is redirected to a new created site.

On this new site i wanna get the closeDate *for example "12/24/2015"* for my countdowntimer as endtime in the `Meteor.startup();` The counter should count from the currentTime, the actual date/time when the form is submitted,  to the closeDate date/time the user entered before in the form. When the actual date/time > `closeDate`, the created site should be closed and the user gets redirected to another page.

Comment: I'm not sure what the bigger picture is here, but have you seen this package: [mizzao:timesync](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/timesync)?

Comment: Which document you want to find is not clear from this question. Can you add more information about what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this as a modeling problem. When you have:

```
 Date.insert({ closeDateDB: closeDate });
```

You are creating a record in MongoDB with a single key *closeDateDB*.

Firstly this isn't indexed by user so it's not clear what you plan to do with these events. `Meteor.startup()` will run for every new user (on either the client or server side, depending on where you define it). Does each one get his/her own action? What happens when there are multiple events in the future?

Secondly, what happens when time is `> closeDate` and the event is *past*?

Some possibilities:

```
// find a single random event in the future
Date.findOne({ closeDateDB: { $gte: new Date() } }); 

// find the next event
Date.findOne({ closeDateDB: { $gte: new Date() } },
  { sort: { closeDateDB: -1}} );

// find the next event for this user (assuming the userId key was added on insert)
Date.findOne({ userId: Meteor.userId(), closeDateDB: { $gte: new Date() } },
  { sort: { closeDateDB: -1}, limit: 1 } ); )
```

Comment: Right, so I think my answer covers all your possible cases. What's missing?

Comment: if i try your answer it throws me Uncaught Error: Unrecognized operator: $ge. Sorry i am a beginner at meteor.js. What is the $ge operator doing here?

Comment: sorry `$gte` - greater than or equal

Comment: if i try your suggestions i am getting an undefined error. Date.findOne(); should be able to return a string like '12 24 2015' but how ...

Comment: If you're not getting any data it probably means that you're not storing the date as a date type (`'12 24 2015'` is *not* a date in Mongo and can't be compared for inequality). When you compare the data with `new Date()` it's always less. Note also that `findOne()` will return an object, not a string.